# Recording Audio/Voice using Cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I want to record a Audio/Voice programmatically using cocos2d.Is there any library available to do this.I am aware of AVAudioFoundation and SimpleAudioEngine.But i don't know how to use this for recording a sound.So i am looking for simple sample to get start with that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not much familiar about cocos2d. But had experience with audio recording using AVAudiorecorder.

Comment: i found some sample code here..http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802..but i don't know it can be used in cocos2d